# Can't Access Files from FormData in React/Node App. TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm creating a scholarship website where users can submit an application. I've created a form and wired it up so that when it's submitted, the form data populates an email which is sent to the person who handles the applicant data, and uploaded PDFs are attached to it. This error keeps popping up on submit though, even though I'm pretty sure I should be selecting the files correctly. During other trials I selected them incorrectly and the email was sent, but while the text data was all correct, the files would be corrupted or something. The error makes it sound like the files are non-existent, but I don't know why that would be.

I had it working at one point by sending the data through regular form submission, but I need to be able to do a .then() statement when it's finished sending the email, and I don't know how to do that with regular form submission. If you can tell me how that works, I'll also accept it as an answer.

Here's my relevant code:

Fetch Request:

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
        const formData = new FormData()
        for (let value in this.state.formValues ) {
        formData.append(value, this.state.formValues[value])
        }
        formData.append('essay', document.getElementById('essay').value)
        formData.append('recLetter1', document.getElementById('recLetter1').value)
        formData.append('recLetter2', document.getElementById('recLetter2').value)
        await fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
    })} catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
}
```

}

Server Side POST handling:

```
const express = require('express')
const sendMail = require('./mail')
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({dest: './uploads/'})
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000
const cpUpload = upload.fields([{name: 'essay', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'recLetter1', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'recLetter2', maxCount: 1}])
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/index.html'))
})

app.post('/', cpUpload, (req, res) => {
    sendMail(req.files['essay'][0], req.files['recLetter1'][0], req.files['recLetter2'][0], req.body, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json({message: 'Internal Error'})
        }
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

sendMail Function:

```
const sendMail = (file1, file2, file3, info) => {
    
            const mailOptions = {
                from: process.env.GMAIL_USER_NAME,
                to: process.env.GMAIL_USER_NAME,
                subject: `New Applicant, ${info.studentFirstName} ${info.studentMI} ${info.studentLastName}`,
                text: 
                `New Applicant - \n
                *Name*: ${info.studentFirstName} ${info.studentMI} ${info.studentLastName}
                *Phone Number*: ${info.studentPhone}
                *Date of Birth*: ${info.studentDOB}
                *Address*: ${info.studentAddress} ${[info.studentAddress2] ? 
                             info.studentAddress2 : ''}
                 ${info.studentCity}, ${info.studentState}, ${info.studentZip}
                 
                // (There's more but I'm sure you get the idea)
                

                attachments: [
                    {
                    filename: `${info.studentFirstName}${info.studentLastName}essay.pdf`,
                    content: file1,
                    contentType: 'application/pdf'
                },
                {
                    filename: `${info.studentFirstName}${info.studentLastName}recLetter1.pdf`,
                    content: file2,
                    contentType: 'application/pdf'
                },
                {
                    filename: `${info.studentFirstName}${info.studentLastName}recLetter2.pdf`,
                    content: file3,
                    contentType: 'application/pdf'
                },
            ]
        }
```

The Error I keep getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at C:\Users\brand\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ShatteredCeilingWebsite\scweb\index.js:24:32
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\brand\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ShatteredCeilingWebsite\scweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\brand\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ShatteredCeilingWebsite\scweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\brand\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ShatteredCeilingWebsite\scweb\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
at listener (C:\Users\brand\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ShatteredCeilingWebsite\scweb\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
at onFinish (C:\Users\brand\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ShatteredCeilingWebsite\scweb\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
at callback (C:\Users\brand\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ShatteredCeilingWebsite\scweb\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10) 
at IncomingMessage.onevent (C:\Users\brand\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ShatteredCeilingWebsite\scweb\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)
```

I think that's all I need to show, but let me know if I missed anything crucial. I've tried setting the Content-Type to both multipart/form-data and undefined, I tried setting the Accept header to '*/*',  I've tried all kinds of combinations of selecting the req.files in the post handler, (That's how the email sometimes goes through with corrupted files), I don't know what to do anymore. Can someone please help me?

Comment: The error log gives some kind of tip: You have an array or something like at `/scweb/index.js` at line 24 that is undefined and tring to access an non-existent position on it (0 in this case). Which one is this file?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using document.getElementById('file').value when I should've been using document.getElementById('file').files[0]